# using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 on production server. I see below log in postgreSQL error log file many times.

LOG : using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding

Some time I feel query execution is slow. What is the cause of this issue and how we can fix it ?

Comment: Postgres creating statistics/... on runtime scans and safes the result inside a separate log file. Afterwards, the logs will be printed BUT it could happen that the scans are not already finnished so this message will occur and a older log will be shown which was already finished. 
So this indicates the scans are to slow - might be I/O performance or to many data. In general if you can life having 1 scan delay it is fine.

Comment: I can  see 0 values in statistics of one DB. I analyzed it still statistics was not updated. What fix we need to do in this case ? Do we need to restart PG service ?

Comment: It might be helpful if you can add additional information like server resources, I/O performance, DB avg usage and table sizes.
Without having detailed information it's just guessing the most common issues.

Comment: Any messages in the log file about the stats collector, other than repeats of that one?

Comment: No other message.  This messages is almost 500 times in a one hour. I tried to get root cause for this and on some blogs it says restart  the PostgreSQL service. I will  check once by restating the PostgreSQL service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted  PostgreSQL service and now no such event found in postgresql error log.  Statistics collector is also working properly now.

"using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding"

Thanks,
Darshan Shah