# Message in Pg_log : 'using stale statistics instead of current ones because the stats collector is not responding'

Tags: postgresql

Pgsql Version : 10.21.

We are consistently receiving below message in the pg_log.

> 'using stale statistics instead of current ones because the stats collector is not responding'

Moreover, we have noticed **significant slowdowns in DB queries occurring randomly**.

Anybody faced this kind of issue and Kindly suggestion any solution for this? Thank you.

Note : As mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251289/using-stale-statistics-instead-of-current-ones-because-stats-collector-is-not-re) restarting is not possible, since this application is in the production setup.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't know where your stats directory is mounted, and don't have monitoring/logs that can show you what was going on when this first happened, otherwise you'd have shared. You're using an out-of-date version of postgresql anyway, so your best bet is to plan and execute an upgrade to something current anyway. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the statistics collector is not working, PostgreSQL does not gather statistics that drive autovacuum and autoanalyze, so it is not surprising if your queries perform badly. It will also lead to worse problems like table bloat.

You will have to figure out why the statistics collector is not working. Can you see the process in the process list? If no, that's the problem. If yes, it may be that you have network problems. I once had a case where the statistics collector listened on IP v6, but IPv6 was disabled later during the startup process. See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/) for a write-up.

You will certainly have to restart the database once you have figured out what the problem is and fixed it. The little down time will be the least of your problems.

Comment: "I once...but IPv6 was..startup process." Verified this case. Only IPV4 is enabled on the Machine. We noticed that Once we get the pg_log error message "using stale statistics instead of current ones because the stats collector is not responding"  the very next query execution got delayed for 3 minutes. So we tried to execute the query again it got executed only in 2 Seconds. Will it be due to the stats collector being updated during the previous query execution?

Also, we are planning to upgrade pgsql version 14.7, will it solve this issue?  Thanks for your help

Comment: In my case, the problem was that IPv6 was still enabled when the statistics collector started. Upgrade to v15 or v16, because the statistics collector got rewritten in v15, and your problem might just disappear. Did you `strace` the statistics collector to see if it was doing something?

Comment: "In my case, the problem was that IPv6 was still enabled when the statistics collector started." - You meant even though IPV6 was disabled, the stats collector was wrongly occupied IPV6 during machine boot up?

Comment: Yes, because IPv6 was still enabled when PostgreSQL started. The boot sequence was buggy. I detailsd that in my article.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

> I once had a case where the statistics collector listened on IP v6,
> but IPv6 was disabled later during the startup process.

Verified this case. Only IPV4 is enabled on the Machine.

> If the statistics collector is not working, PostgreSQL does not gather
> statistics that drive autovacuum and autoanalyze, so it is not
> surprising if your queries perform badly.

This gave us some insights to us. We noticed that Once we get the below message in the pg_logs the very next query execution got delayed for 3 minutes. So we tried to execute the query again it got executed **only in 2 Seconds**.  Will it be due to the stats collector being updated during the previous query execution?

> 'using stale statistics instead of current ones because the stats collector is not responding'

Also, we are planning to upgrade pgsql version 14.7, will it solve this issue ?